# Surviving TPL, Delegates, Threads, and Invokes

Tags: winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm facing a serious problem of deadlock in a multithreaded desktop/windows application. I fear I'm not using the correct approach to delegates in a very async environment. Also, even though I "sink" my events into the calling UI thread, if possible, I still have to Invoke on the UI thread to see some action. Follows, is the details.

The application is basically a client for users of an online file storage service. That service exposes functionality through REST calls. I first created a managed code wrapper DLL for such calls that allows for a .NET consumer to create a static instance of this DLL and call the functions. I'll take the file upload operation as an example.

Now, in the wrapper, here is the public interface for a file upload:

```
public Int32 UploadFile(FileSystemObject FolderToUploadTo, FileInfo LocalFileAndPath, OperationProgressReportEventHandler onOperationProgressReport, FileSystemObjectUploadCompletedEventHandler onOperationCompleted) {
        Int32 ReplyNumber = 0;
        try {
            var TheOperation = new UploadFileObjectOperation(FolderToUploadTo, LocalFileAndPath, _User.APIKey) {
                onProgressReport = onOperationProgressReport,
                onUploadCompleted = onOperationCompleted
            };

            //Add it to the pool of operations
            OperationPool.Add(TheOperation);

            //Start the operation through the factory
            OperationFactory.StartNew(() => {
                TheOperation.Start();
            });

            //Chain the *actual* TPL Task to flush after usage
            TheOperation.InnerTask.ContinueWith(t => {
                t.Dispose(); //Dispose the inner task
                OperationPool.Remove(TheOperation); //Remove the operation from the pool
                TheOperation = null; //Nullify the Operation                
            });

            ReplyNumber = TheOperation.TaskId;
        }
        catch {
            ReplyNumber = 0;
        }

        return ReplyNumber;
    }
```

As you can see, the actual UI application, that will refer this DLL, will be sending delegates for progress and completed to the operation(s). Now, the body of the operation itself:

```
public class UploadFileObjectOperation : BaseOperation, IDisposable {

    //Store

    public FileSystemObjectUploadCompletedEventHandler onUploadCompleted;

    //Constructors
    //Disposing stuff

    protected override void PerformWork() {
        try {
            //Init the WebClient
            UploadClient.UploadProgressChanged += (UploadProgressChanged_s, UploadProgressChanged_e) => {
                //This is my event in base class being raised
                ReportProgress(UploadProgressChanged_e.ProgressPercentage, UploadProgressChanged_e);
            };

            UploadClient.UploadFileCompleted += (UploadFileCompleted_s, UploadFileCompleted_e) => {
                if (UploadFileCompleted_e.Error != null) {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Upload failed. " + UploadFileCompleted_e.Error.Message);
                }
                JObject JSONLiveObject = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UploadFileCompleted_e.Result));

                if (String.Compare((String)JSONLiveObject["status"], Constants._CONST_RESTRESPONSE_STATUS_VALUE_FAIL, false) == 0) {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Upload response failed. " + (String)JSONLiveObject["result"]["message"]);
                }

                //Eureka! Success! We have an upload!
                //This is my event being raised
                UploadTaskCompleted(new UploadFileObjectOperationEventArg {
                    Error = null,
                    ResultSource = OperationResultSource.Fresh,
                    Status = OperationExitStatus.Success,
                    TaskId = TaskId,
                    UploadedFileSystemObject = _UploadedFile
                });
            };

            //Start the async upload
            UploadClient.UploadFileAsync(AddressOfRESTURI, UploadingMethod, _FileToUpload.FullName);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException exp_Canceled) {
            UploadTaskCompleted(new UploadFileObjectOperationEventArg {
                Error = exp_Canceled,
                ResultSource = OperationResultSource.Fresh,
                Status = OperationExitStatus.Canceled,
                TaskId = TaskId,
                UploadedFileSystemObject = _UploadedFile
            });
            // To ensure that the calling code knows the task was canceled
            //throw;
        }
        catch (Exception exp) {
            UploadTaskCompleted(new UploadFileObjectOperationEventArg {
                Error = exp,
                ResultSource = OperationResultSource.Fresh,
                Status = OperationExitStatus.Error,
                TaskId = TaskId,
                UploadedFileSystemObject = _UploadedFile
            });
            // If the calling code also needs to know.
            //throw;
        }
    }

    protected void UploadTaskCompleted(UploadFileObjectOperationEventArg arg) {
        if (onUploadCompleted == null)
            return;

        //Sinking into calling UI thread, if possible
        if (onUploadCompleted.Target is Control) {
            Control targetForm = onUploadCompleted.Target as Control;
            targetForm.Invoke(onUploadCompleted, new object[] { arg });
        }
        else {
            onUploadCompleted(arg);
        }

        Status = OperationRunningStatus.Completed;
    }

}
```

The `PerformWork()` raises the two events: Progress reporting and completion. Note that while raising an event, I check if can get a route to the calling thread and push the event directly so to avoid invokes at UI.

Now, lets see how I'm using all of the above in a desktop client:

```
private void UploadFile(FileInfo DraggedFileInfo, FileSystemObject ParentDefination) {
    SessionLifetimeStuff.APICore.UploadFile(ParentDefination, DraggedFileInfo,
    (PercentageCompleted) => {
        #region Progress
        this.InvokeEx(f => {
            UpdateTaskProgress(newTaskQueue.OID, PercentageCompleted.Progress, PercentageCompleted);
        });
        #endregion
    }, (Result) => {
        #region Completion
        this.InvokeEx(f => {
            switch (Result.Status) {
                case OperationExitStatus.Success:
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File: {0} uploaded to {1}", Result.UploadedFileSystemObject.DocumentFullname, Result.UploadedFileSystemObject.FolderId));
                    break;
                case OperationExitStatus.Canceled:
                    DialogManager.ShowDialog(DialogTypeEnum.Warning, "Dropbox", "Upload canceled.", null, this);
                    break;
                case OperationExitStatus.Error:
                    DialogManager.ShowDialog(DialogTypeEnum.Error, "Dropbox", "Upload failed.", Result.Error, this);
                    break;
            }
        });
        #endregion
    });
}
```

I'm using an extension method I found on Stackoverflow for adding the Invoking functionality:
    public static class InvokeExtensions {

```
    public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : Control {
        if (@this.InvokeRequired) {
            @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
        }
        else {
            if (!@this.IsHandleCreated)
                return;
            if (@this.IsDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("@this is disposed.");

            action(@this);
        }
    }

    public static IAsyncResult BeginInvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action)
        where T : Control {
        return @this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => @this.InvokeEx(action)));
    }

    public static void EndInvokeEx<T>(this T @this, IAsyncResult result)
        where T : Control {
        @this.EndInvoke(result);
    }

}
```

In my code, i have commented out the invokes as I though i don't need then as the events being raised are coming in sinked. However, i realized that my UI was not doing anything at all. So, I added the `InvokeEx({ code; })` and my UI started to shoe activity.

Now, why do I need to invoke?

If I attempt different operations from UI, eventually, my UI freezes although the application still behaves as normally functioning.

I found an old article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649143.aspx#scag-ch06_topic4 that described the usage of delegates and I see that there is a IAsyncResult involved.

Could someone point me as to where I'm going wrong here?

**Update:**
Ok, with the invoking code commented on the UI, I get no activity at all. But upon using the `this.InvokeEx` or wrapping a work in `this.BeginInvokeEx`, I get UI updates but after a while, here are the two exceptions occurring (in this order):

- Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
- A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Comment: Could you put the answer as answer? This would help others in searching for answers to resolve problems

Comment: This is old but I believe I didn't found a working solution to this one. Had to re-do using a different approach. There were too many loose-ends to this method. I'll have to dig around to find out what made the thing work.